# R - re-order columns based on match (template)

Tags: r, list, sorting

So I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
     V1       V2   V3         V4
1 Sleep Domestic  Eat Child Care
2 Sleep Domestic  Eat       Paid
3 Sleep Domestic  Eat Child Care
4 Sleep      Eat Paid       <NA>
```

What I would like to do is to `reorder` the columns based on a "template"

```
["Sleep", "Eat", "Domestic", "Paid", "Child care"]
```

To get (ouput)

```
   V1    V2       V3      V4            V5
Sleep   Eat Domestic      NA    Child Care
Sleep   Eat Domestic    Paid            NA
Sleep   Eat Domestic      NA    Child Care
Sleep   Eat       NA    Paid            NA
```

So in columns 1 `Sleep`, columns 2 `Eat`, ...

I have no idea where to start with this. 
Any idea ?

**data**

```
x = structure(list(V1 = c("Sleep", "Sleep", "Sleep", "Sleep"), V2 = c("Domestic", 
"Domestic", "Domestic", "Eat"), V3 = c("Eat", "Eat", "Eat", "Paid"
), V4 = c("Child Care", "Paid", "Child Care", NA)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

template = c('Sleep', 'Eat', 'Domestic', 'Paid', 'Child care')
```

Comment: You have a case mismatch - "Child care" to "Child Care"

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, so let me propose what I think you're asking, then you tell me where I'm wrong, ok? Basically each column *should* represent having a value or not having a value, for instance: `[4,'V5']` should either be "Child Care" (meaning "yes" for child care), or "NA" meaning "No" for child care. And the order of these yes/no values should be ordered in each row according to the template. Is that true?

Comment: @TravisHeeter Hi yes actually it is another way to look at it. I didnt think about it that way but yes.

Comment: Extending @TravisHeeter 's comment, something like `table(row(x), factor(as.matrix(x), template))` might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(x, 'id') %>% 
       gather(Var, Val, -id, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
       mutate(Var = factor(Val, levels = template)) %>% 
       spread(Var, Val) %>% 
       select(-id) %>% 
       setNames(., paste0("V", seq_along(template)))
#     V1  V2       V3   V4         V5
#1 Sleep Eat Domestic <NA> Child Care
#2 Sleep Eat Domestic Paid       <NA>
#3 Sleep Eat Domestic <NA> Child Care
#4 Sleep Eat     <NA> Paid       <NA>
```

Comment: @giacomoV  Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `rowSums` for each `template` value and then piece it together again:

```
template <- c("Sleep", "Eat", "Domestic", "Paid", "Child Care")
# i've fixed this template so the case matches the values for 'Child Care'

data.frame(lapply(
  setNames(template, seq_along(template)),
  function(v) c(NA,v)[(rowSums(x==v,na.rm=TRUE)>0)+1]
))

#     X1  X2       X3   X4         X5
#1 Sleep Eat Domestic <NA> Child Care
#2 Sleep Eat Domestic Paid       <NA>
#3 Sleep Eat Domestic <NA> Child Care
#4 Sleep Eat     <NA> Paid       <NA>
```

Or an alternative using `pmax`:

```
data.frame(
  lapply(
    setNames(template, seq_along(template)), 
    function(v) do.call(pmax, c(replace(x, x != v,NA),na.rm=TRUE)) 
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A reshape2 and dplyr solution. Clearly not as compact as others. The idea is to melt(make tall), order factor, and cast.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

# make and id column 
x$id <- row.names(x)

# make a tall result id, var, value
tall <- x %>% 
  melt(id.vars="id") %>%
  select(id, value) 

# make an ordered factor with the template
tall$value <- factor(tall$value, levels=template, ordered = TRUE) 

# make wide result with dcast
result <-  tall %>%  
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%  # drop the NAs 
  mutate(var = value) %>%    # name the column the same as the value
  dcast(id ~ var)            # make into wide format

result
#  id Sleep Eat Domestic Paid Child Care
#1  1 Sleep Eat Domestic <NA> Child Care
#2  2 Sleep Eat Domestic Paid       <NA>
#3  3 Sleep Eat Domestic <NA> Child Care
#4  4 Sleep Eat     <NA> Paid       <NA>
```